# Finding a Static Site Generator that allows me to add javascript animations using threejs and mathboxjs

Tags: javascript, static-site-generator

I am looking for static website generator to develop a personal blog. I want to include javascript animations into the posts, to visualize data or various examine some math models. However, I have not found any static generator that allows me to include javascript files in my posts.

Now perhaps I am looking in the wrong places. Not sure if there is a way to include this feature in any existing static generator. Any recommendations out there on a good software solutions to this purpose.

Comment: Is there anything special about including it? SSG typically allow you to define the markup yourself (for the template as well as the content), so you could simply add the `script` elements directly, no?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is right. I was just not sure if it was this simple. I will try this in a few different SSGs and see if it works.